# Show wordpress sidebar element based on a variable generated on single.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

Me again! I'll try and be as informative, yet concise, as possible here. I've created a loop to display a DJ mix and its associated information, such as event venue, mix date, runtime, etc. Also on the page I have created an if...else conditional statement which checks the mix venue against all the event posts, and displays any upcoming events at that venue (the if part) as with [this mix](http://djryanmcnally.flyfx.co.uk/mixes/october-mix/)!. If there are no events scheduled for that venue, it checks against event venues and displays photo's from that event instead by setting a variable ($up_events) to none, and displays photos from the venue if $up_events is set to 'none' as with [this mix](http://djryanmcnally.flyfx.co.uk/mixes/text-mix-one/)!.

The reason I want to display one or the other, is to keep the pages neat and tidy, as I am short of sidebar content, and I don't particularly want to pad it out with irrelevant widgets just so the page looks even. What I WOULD like to do is, if there are upcoming events scheduled, the $up_event variable isn't set to 'none', instead, said events are shown as usual, but I would like to show photos from that event in the sidebar. I tried editing sidebar.php beneath the widgetised areas with;

```
if (($up_events != 'none')){ include 'related_photos_sidebar.php'; } else echo ''
```

to display the photos if $up_events is NOT equal to none (i.e, there are upcoming events shown), which didn't work. For testing purposes, I also tried;

```
if (($up_events == 'none')){ include 'related_photos_sidebar.php'; } else echo ''
```

to see if it would work, even if there were no upcoming events, but again, that didn't work. I'm assuming it may need to be a global variable? But, i'm not entirely sure. Any ideas how I would go about this? I tried var_dump on $up_events in the sidebar, and it comes back NULL in either scenario, how do I get the info from single.php, to sidebar.php?

Comment: EDIT: In the last few mins, I've got the related photos to show correctly, but it's still not conditional on the $up_events variable...

Comment: `if ... else` is not a loop.

Comment: Conditional statement then. Any help to offer, or just semantics and pedanticism?

Comment: I would do it with a global variable declared at the top file.

Comment: I tried declaring $up_events as a global variable in header.php, index.php and single.php, but no beans on any of them :(

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to know where you are declaring the var $up_events and if it is correct.
so i'm guessing its in single.php ?  if so then after you get its value from the dbase.  echo it.

```
echo ("I'm in single and up_events=" . $up_events);
```

then go into sidebar.php and do the same.

```
echo ("I'm in sidebar and up_events=" . $up_events);
```

you'll probably get nothing for the second one in sidebar.  the sidebars are normally generated by running the get_sidebar('primary'); function - you should see this inside single.php.  If that's the case then you just need to put the global $up_events command inside sidebar.  hope that helped.

Comment: The var is declared in loop-mixes.php, which is called from single-mixes.php. The code for creating and displaying upcoming events or related photos is immediately after the main loop in loop-mixes.php, you can see the entire code [here](http://pastebin.com/uMAadCgS)! , the code's probably a bit scrappy, and i've probably gone about this the wrong way, but i'm teaching myself php as I go with this website, so you'll have to forgive me! lol!

Comment: Additionally, the line in sidebar.php which checks if up_events is set to none is

    if (($up_events != 'none')){ include 'related_photos_sidebar.php'; } else echo '';

And the code it calls can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/kF5bQGD2)!

Comment: ok not sure i'm following this very well but you need to check the value of those vars so echo them out and make sure the code is going into the if statements.  in the first code put

echo "In FILENAME HERE up_events=" . $up_events . "<br>";
if($up_events =='none'){ // Only if $up_events is set to 'none', display related photos
               
                include 'related_photos.php'; // Displays photos related to this venue
               
                } else echo ''; ?>

then do a similar thing in the second and see what you get out.